# Añadir texto a JTextField usando MVC

Tags: java, mvc

Quisiera saber como añadir un texto a un JTextField usando modelo-vista-controlador (MVC).
En la ventana tengo un JTextField creado de nombre elemDisponibles y el siguiente codigo:

```
public void setElemDisponibles(String s) {
    this.elemDisponibles.setText(s);
}
```

En el controlador pulsando un boton me muestra el texto por consola:

```
protected void teclaPulsada() {
    modelo.mostrarPlacas();
}
```

Esto es una lista de objetos.

En modelo tengo:

```
public void mostrarPlacas();
```

El cual hace:

```
public void mostrarPlacas(){
    System.out.println("Placas disponibles en almacen: ");
    for(Producto p : map_catalogo.values()) {
      if( p instanceof Plaques) {
        System.out.println(p);
      }
    }
}
```

Si lo cambio a String no se como continuar..

Para que lo muestre en el jtextfield he probado poniendo:

```
protected void teclaTorrePulsada() {
    vista.setElemDisponibles(modelo.mostrarPlacas());
}
```

Entiendo que setElemDisponibles es String y mostrarProducto() es una lista de objetos por lo cual no es compatible. No se como cambiarlo para hacerlo funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Puedes poner el código de tu método mostrarProducto().. Al parecer este método es void, sí es el caso debes de cambiarlo (void por String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que dentro de tu método `mostrarProductos()` tienes el método `mostrarPlacas()`.
Tu método `mostrarPlacas()` debería retornar un `String`al igual que tu método `mostrarProductos()`.

```
public String mostrarPlacas(){
    String placas = "";
    System.out.println("Placas disponibles en almacen: ");
    for(Producto p : map_catalogo.values()) {
      if( p instanceof Plaques) {
        placas += p + "\n";
      }
    }
   return placas;
}
```

En `mostrarProductos()`:

```
public String mostrarProductos() {
   return mostrarPlacas();
}
```

Así lo he entendido yo, sino podrías poner el código de `mostrarProductos()`

Comment: Genial respuesta gracias, el unico problema es que ahora el listado de placas me sale consecutivo y no uno debajo del otro, como podria modificar esto?

Comment: Añadiendo un `"\n"` detrás del objeto `p`. Ya he actualizado mi respuesta.